# Playing Video in JFrame?

Tags: java, video

I'm trying to play video within a JFrame, I've been looking around online for a while and everything I have tried (VLCJ, Xuggger i think its called) doesn't work, the errors I get can I can never seem to fix, the closest I have gotten is using JMF which is very old, it can never play a video file but as mentioned, it's the furthust I've gotten. Is there any good little API's / examples I can look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends on the video, however there are a few build in mechanism.

You could use java fx http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/simpleplayer.htm

And then build javafx into your JFrame, like here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm

If embedding in java seems to be a bad solution, there is always the possibility to open the systems media player:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("the.mp4"));
```